# Is there a standard way to check for Infinite and NaN in Fortran 90/95?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I've been trying to find a standards-compliant way to check for Infinite and NaN values in Fortran 90/95 but it proved harder than I thought.

- I tried to manually create Inf and NaN variables using the binary representation described in IEEE 754, but I found no such functionality.
- I am aware of the intrinsic `ieee_arithmetic` module in Fortran 2003 with the `ieee_is_nan()` and `ieee_is_finite()` intrinsic functions. However it's not supported by all the compilers ([notably gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29383) as of version 4.9).

Defining infinity and NaN at the beginning like `pinf = 1. / 0` and `nan = 0. / 0` seems hackish to me and IMHO can raise some building problems - for example if some compilers check this in compile time one would have to provide a special flag.

Is there a way I can implement in standard Fortran 90/95?

```
function isinf(x)
! Returns .true. if x is infinity, .false. otherwise
...
end function isinf
```

and `isnan()`?

Comment: gnu fortran 4.10 [fixes this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29383#c16)

Comment: GCC 5 and more recent do support `IEEE_ARITHMETIC`, but support of older versions is still an issue and will continue to be for a long time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simple way without using the `ieee_arithmatic` is to do the following.

**Infinity**:  Define your variable `infinity = HUGE(dbl_prec_var)` (or, if you have it, a quad precision variable). Then you can simply check to see if your variable is infinity by `if(my_var > infinity)`.

**NAN**: This is even easier. By definition, NAN is not equal to anything, even itself. Simply compare the variable to itself: `if(my_var /= my_var)`.

Comment: Odd that nobody else mentioned the NaN case. I guess they were worried that you might be using fortran on a non-ieee cpu? Aside from that, the NaN check is very robust. The infinity check, on the other hand, is a bit less elegant, since it depends on the data type.

Comment: @amaurea: You can take care of the data-type issue by using `INTERFACE` and linking the few types you might be using into the same `MODULE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: @IanH: You could reasonably set `infinity = 1.e100_dp` and still obtain a good infinity checker. Even when using small scales (like 1e-24 m) to describe big scales (like 1e+24 m), you still are no where near 1e100.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and good catch about the `MODULE PROCEDURE`. One can make a very clean interface with it. If my code is worth it I might release it. Thanks again!

Comment: An optimizer will indeed optimize the check out if fast_math or similar is requested. Alas, it will even optimize out the gfortran's `isnan` intrinsic. It is the programmer's responsibility to take care about this when he requests unsecure fast math and still wants to detect NaN.

Comment: HUGE is the largest non-infinity; the condition `myvar > HUGE(myvar)` should only be true if myvar is infinite, but naming HUGE(myvar) as infinity is misleading.

Comment: How much of this answer is functional vs. standard-compliant? In other words, is this how it *ought* to be done, or is this just how it *can* be done?

Comment: @jvriesem using `iee_arithmetic` is how it *should* be done (so if your compiler doesn't support it, get a different/better compiler). This is a standards-compliant way that is reasonably functional: variables are "infinite" when larger than a value that doesn't make sense for the code (and infinitesimal when smaller than a certain value); the NaN check could be optimized with some compilers though.

Comment: I tried to check for `NaN` in `nvfortran` using `if(my_var /= my_var)`, but it didn't work. Hopefully, the alternative expression  `if((my_var-my_var) /= 0)` did work in the newer compilers (2022/2023). NOTE: I know all is supposed to work, but I can provide a code example showing that `if(my_var /= my_var)` fails.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I'll "answer" regarding Rick Thompson's suggestion for testing infinity.

```
if (A-1 .eq. A)
```

This will also be true if A is a very large floating point number, and `1` is below the precision of A.

A simple test:

```
subroutine test_inf_1(A)
    real, intent(in) :: A
    print*, "Test (A-1 == A)"
    if (A-1 .eq. A) then
        print*, "    INFINITY!!!"
    else
        print*, "    NOT infinite"
    endif
end subroutine

subroutine test_inf_2(A)
    real, intent(in) :: A
    print*, "Test (A > HUGE(A))"
    if (A > HUGE(A)) then
        print*, "    INFINITY!!!"
    else
        print*, "    NOT infinite"
    endif
end subroutine


program test
    real :: A,B

    A=10
    print*, "A = ",A
    call test_inf_1(A)
    call test_inf_2(A)
    print*, ""

    A=1e20
    print*, "A = ",A
    call test_inf_1(A)
    call test_inf_2(A)
    print*, ""

    B=0.0 ! B is necessary to trick gfortran into compiling this
    A=1/B
    print*, "A = ",A
    call test_inf_1(A)
    call test_inf_2(A)
    print*, ""

end program test
```

outputs:

```
A =    10.0000000    
Test (A-1 == A)
    NOT infinite
Test (A > HUGE(A))
    NOT infinite

A =    1.00000002E+20
Test (A-1 == A)
    INFINITY!!!
Test (A > HUGE(A))
    NOT infinite

A =          Infinity
Test (A-1 == A)
    INFINITY!!!
Test (A > HUGE(A))
    INFINITY!!!
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The salient parts of IEEE_ARITHMETIC for generating/checking for NaN's are easy enough to write for gfortran for a particular architecture.

Comment: About your second statement, they don't seem to agree http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2012-10/msg00580.html or am I missing something?

Comment: Btw I added a link to the relevant gfortran bug (which dates from 2006 and has status NEW).

Comment: Writing *all* of IEEE_ARITHMETIC for *all* architectures that gfortran supports, which is what that bug deals with, would be difficult!  Writing the select bits that generate/check for NaN's, on a particular architecture (for example, x64) is pretty easy.  See https://sites.google.com/site/tprincesite/Home/gfortran-ieee-arithmetic for one example by Tim Prince that relies on the inequality of any two NaN's, an alternative approach is to use the Fortran bit intrinsics to generate/test for the specific patterns that indicate a NaN.  (See the "original" gfortran bug 29383 for more discussion.)

Answer (score 2):

I have used:

```
  PROGRAM MYTEST
  USE, INTRINSIC :: IEEE_ARITHMETIC, ONLY: IEEE_IS_FINITE      
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: number, test
  number = 'the expression to test'
  test = number/number
  IF (IEEE_IS_FINITE(test)) THEN
     WRITE(*,*) 'We are OK'
  ELSE
     WRITE(*,*) 'Got a problem'
  END IF         
     WRITE(*,*) number, test
  END PROGRAM MYTEST
```

This will print 'Got a problem' for number = 0.0D0, 1.0D0/0.0D0, 0.0D0/0.0D0, SQRT(-2.0D0), and also for overflows and underflows such as number = EXP(1.0D800) or number = EXP(-1.0D800). Notice that generally, things like number = EXP(1.0D-800) will just set number = 1.0 and produce a warning at compilation time, but the program will print 'We are OK', which I find acceptable.

OL.

Comment: The question asks for NotANumber, but your exampletests for finiteness. It will also catch +Inf and -Inf as false positives. Also notice that the question was really mainly interested about what to do when `IEEE_ARITHMETIC` is not available and asks how to do that using Fortran 90/95.

Comment: In addition to Vladimir F's concerns, there's no guarantee that even with `ieee_arithmetic` that `ieee_support_datatype(test)` is true.  If it isn't, it is not permitted to consider `ieee_is_finite(test)`.

Comment: I was bit too harsh, the question does also ask for an equivalent of `IEEE_IS_FINITE()`. But the point is that the OP knows it exists but asks for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

for testing NaN none of the things worked eg.if testing real s2p to see if it is NaN then

```
if(isnan(s2p))
```

did not work in gfortran nor did

```
if(s2p.ne.s2p).
```

The only thing that worked was

```
if(.not.s2p<1.and..not.s2p>1)
```

though to make real sure u may want to add

```
if(.not.s2p<1.and..not.s2p>1.and..not.s2p==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Neither is there a standards-compliant way of checking for infinities or NaNs in Fortran 90/95, nor can there be a standards-compliant way.  There is no standards-compliant way of defining either of these quasi-numbers in Fortran 90/95.

Comment: Well, in the scope of the IEEE Floating Point standard, that is.

Answer (score 0):

For Fortran, 1/infinity=0
thus, divide your variable by zero
i.e

```
program test
implicit none
real :: res
integer :: i

do i=1,1000000
    res=-log((1.+(10**(-real(i))))-1.)
    print*,i,res
    if ((1./res)==0.) then
        exit
    end if
end do

end program
```

there's your infinity check. No complication necessary.

Answer (score -2):

For Inf it seems to work that if (A-1 .eq. A) is true, then A is Inf

Comment: Maybe you might want to elaborate a bit more.