# Handling NaN, Infinity and numbers larger than double precision in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am currently running a computation model in Fortran. During calculation, sometimes I got "NaN", "Infinity" and numbers larger than double precision (shows as **************). And I need to detect them. I can detect "NaN" with the following command.

```
if(isnan(result))then
   continue = .false.
else
   continue = .true.
endif
```

I don't know how to detect "Infinity" and "************" (numbers larger than double precision).

How do I do this?

Comment: The asterisks do not mean that numbers are "larger than double precision", but instead that they overflow the format specifier when printing. This can e.g. occur if you print a two digit integer using only one character.

Comment: Do you have a complier which supports the `ieee_*` intrinsic modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard way to check for Infinite and NaN in Fortran 90/95?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389958/is-there-a-standard-way-to-check-for-infinite-and-nan-in-fortran-90-95)

Comment: Alexander Vogt - thanks for your comment. Yes, I will check about that. for the link you gave, I already checked and my compiler doesn't recognise "isinf".

francescalus - I don't know how to check if my compiler supports  ieee_*.

Comment: If you're using gfortran before 5.0 you won't be.  Many other compilers do, but the best way would be to check the documentation (or just try `use ieee_arithmetic; end`).  That said, the answers in the linked question give a good selection of possibilities.

Comment: You have tagged as [tag:fortran90] and [tag:fortran95] (which some view as strictly contradicting each other).  Does that mean you wish to ignore answers relating to the standardized IEEE aspects of more recent Fortran?  [You now say your compiler doesn't support these, but it could be an ideal to aim for in the future.]

Answer (score 0):

Now, I solved the asterisks with the following command (although it may not be that efficient). Thanks Alexander Vogt.

```
  if(isnan(result))then
     continue = .false.
  elseif(result.gt.1.d20)then
     continue = .false.
  else
     continue = .true.
  endif
```

However, I still cannot solve "Infinity". I tried "IEEE" but my compiler didn't support.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just check if `result > huge(result)`?

Comment: for robustness you should catch -infinity too.  `abs(x)<=huge(x)` catches all three `+/-inf` and `NAN`  (I should say I don't know if that's guaranteed to work per standards )

Comment: @agentp unfortunately `abs(x) <= huge(x)` does not detect `NaN` in fast-math mode like gfortran with `-O3 -ffast-math` compiler flags.